# Checkbox automatic selection problem with JQuery

Tags: jquery

This works before clicking on the checkbox value with the mouse. But, if the checkbox value is changed with mouse click, it does not work. It should work when you click the button. I want it to work when I click on the button, even if changes are made with the mouse. How to solve this problem?

Codes are here; https://jsfiddle.net/d3vman/zcwku03p/11/

```
$(function() {
        $("#click").click(function() {
           var control = $("#checkboxId").is(":checked");
           if (control == false) {
               $(":checkbox").attr("checked", true);
           } else {
               $(":checkbox").attr("checked", false);
           }
       });
    });
```

Comment: change `.attr` to `.prop`

Comment: It stops working because changing the tickbox updates the tickbox's `checked` *property* - as it now has a property, it doesn't use the attribute - so changing the attribute no longer has an effect.

Comment: @Alivetodie-Anant This worked. I tried it for Firefox and Chrome. Thanks.

Comment: @freedomn-m so ist his solution a bad way to go?  By the way, thank you all.

Comment: Just a tip, you don't need to add "(SOLVED)" into the title, the site will automatically mark which questions are resolved (either with a closed state or by indicating an answer has been accepted)

Comment: @Devman apologies for the confusion - my (remaining/not-deleted) comment explains what you are seeing with attr, where it works at first then stops working.  There were some other (now deleted) comments where another user couldn't reproduce the issue.   For complete clarity: the first comment is the recommended solution:  use `.prop`